# Electron Js application menu click works for more than one time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, menu, electron, click

```
label: 'color',
      click: function (item, focusedWindow, event) {
        contents.send(constants.APPLICATION_MENU.ARTICLE.EVENT, 'BLUE')
      }
```

main.js

And listening the event in renderer using:

```
ipcRenderer.on(constants.APPLICATION_MENU.ARTICLE.EVENT, (event, action) => {
console.log('called')}
```

this is called twice or sometimes thrice. Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong in here. Thanks

Comment: Use `.once` instead of `.on` on `ipcRenderer`, otherwise the listener will keep listening until an `off` against the same channel is invoked (hence registering multiple time will invoke multiple time). https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereroncechannel-listener Otherwise, you need to manually remove the listener through `removeListener`

Comment: @briosheje Thanks for replying, This menu item should work multiple times as in every time users click on the menu, but when I use "once" instead on "on" the menu only worked for once and clicking it on the second time it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely relies on this piece of code:

```
ipcRenderer.on(constants.APPLICATION_MENU.ARTICLE.EVENT, (event, action) => {
console.log('called')}
```

being probably invoked "multiple times" where by "multiple times" i mean that the block that executes this code might be ran multiple times due to view rerenders or window respawns.

Actually, it is the intented behavior that the event is invoked multiple times.

If you want the callback to be invoked just once, use `.once` instead, as [explained in the official docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereroncechannel-listener):

> Adds a **one time listener** function for the event. This listener is invoked only the next time a message is sent to channel, after which it is removed.

Otherwise, you must manually "Unsubscribe" from the channel through [`removeListener`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererremovelistenerchannel-listener), although I don't recommend you to follow this approach, since in your case you just need to register once.

An optimal design would still use `removeListener` whenever you're aware that the listener is not needed anymore.

Comment: IpcRenderer code runs multiple times. According to functionality it should run once per click (click on application menu- menu item). But it's firing multiple times.And using once does not work here, as it worked only once and when I click second time it didn't run.

Comment: If it's firing multiple times, it's because it is being registered **multiple times**.

Comment: I have added the code above. What I'm doing is if a menu item is clicked, sending the event using webContents and listening it in the renderer with ipcRenderer.on just the one time(I have not registered it multiple times). As I'm new to this Can you please tell me if I have done anything wrong?